# Copy drive A to drive B on mount

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, mount, rsync

I need some help with the problem of an automatic copy from drive A --> drive B.

I want to detect a drive on mount as A - 1st mounted drive is A, as source drive.  Detect the 2nd mounted drive as B - destination drive.

As soon as both drives are mounted, I want to automatically create a new folder and copy the content of drive A to the new folder on drive B.  (In my case drive A will be an SD card, and drive B will be a harddisk or a USB drive).

How can I automate this process, perhaps using something like rsync for the copying?

Comment: When you have both drives mounted, the only thing you need to do is `cp -r source destination` if you want to copy something.

Comment: Once this is set up, any time you have two storage devices plugged in, the action will happen automatically.  Do you really want that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, rsync is likely the best bet. You could of course just copy the files but rsync provides for resuming interrupted copies and personally I find the output generated by rsync very helpful in dumping the output to a log file and review later if any errors are reported. Additionally since rsync will compare source to target, you will only be copying over changes and not re-copying all the files over every time.

So again, yes, rsync will likely be the way to go. Good luck.

Comment: Ok good, but how I can detect the drives?
Is there a easy way to copy them on mount event?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use "UDEV" - When the drive is plugged in, UDEV should be provide unique identifiers, and you can trigger a script based on those identifiers to then mount and rsync the drive.

Pages walking you through variants of this process can be found [here](http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2009/09/25/automatic-backups-with-udev/), h[ere](http://www.techpository.com/?page_id=1052) and [here](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/75-debian/54-debian-udev-backup).